# Solr sometimes stop returning results for the query in production.

Tags: java, solr, solrj

we are using solr 6.6 in production and have massive query load. We have one master and two slaves which replicate from master in polling interval of 5 minutes.  We have data import handler which runs every hour to index data from mysql db to solr master. we are using solrj for querying solr slaves from java application. It has happened twice in the production that solr did not return results for the query and starts working fine after we execute data import. 
I am not able to find the root cause for this.

Comment: Does the log on the slaves or master say anything in particular when this happens? Could it be caused by delta queries either removing everything or issuing a commit before the import has happened?

Comment: I am suspicious you are seeing a Thread deadlock issue - next time the problem occurs use this documentation https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/thread-dump.html  and look at the thread dump - if you have any BLOCKED threads definitely repost that here. Otherwise what @MatsLindh said is right - anything in the logs? In the meantime you might want to set the timeAllowed parameter https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-ThetimeAllowedParameter